# Whether travel expense related to training for a contract employee will be consider as an expense for tax deduction?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, travel

Whether travel expense related to training for a contract employee will be consider as an expense for tax deduction?

I work for a company on their W-2 as a contract employee. I traveled for a training and will be travelling to attend some technology expo.

My clarification :- Can i consider those travel expenses ( stay / food ) for my tax deduction. Please Note : Mentioned travels are not part of the company program. I traveled or willing to travel on my own desire of learning.

Comment: Bad news: "Deductions for Unreimbursed Employee Expenses
You can no longer claim any miscellaneous itemized deductions that are subject to the 2% of adjusted gross income limitation, including unreimbursed employee expenses. However, you may be able to deduct certain unreimbursed employee business expenses if you fall into one of the following categories of employment"... full details in Publication 529 https://www.irs.gov/publications/p529

Comment: @BenVoigt -Thank you for the details. I had a plan to visit a Tech expo, but i decided to cancel..If the expenses are not deducted, then it will be expensive for me to make a trip ..  thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can deduct travel expenses (see IRS publication 463), however, the drawback is that if you itemize expenses, then you can no longer claim the standard deduction. The standard deduction for 2020 is $12,400 so if your total deductions for the year are less than this, you are better off taking the standard deduction as opposed to itemizing deductions.

Comment: Thank you @Five Bagger, My expenses are less than $3000. So, i would go for Standard Deduction. Thank you again :)